# jekyll author image in article list

Tags: jekyll, liquid

please how can I show the author personal image if I have id defined in collections:

My collection `/_authors/`

```yaml
name: John Doe
image: assets/img/photo-john.jpg
layout: author
permalink: "/authors/john-doe/"
```

How do I show it in the article loop?

```html
{% for post in site.posts %}
    {% assign author = site.authors[page.author] %}
    <img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/{{ author.image }}" alt="{{ post.author }}" class="avatar avatar-sm">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45533735/author-name-url-issue-in-jekyll

Comment: This might also be helpful: https://dev.to/m0nica/how-to-add-author-bio-to-posts-in-jekyll-3g1

Comment: Is in your `_authors` folder a SINGLE file with all authors? Or there are a file PER author?

Comment: I have a .md file per each author

Answer (score 0):

What about `{{ author.image }}` and `relative_url`?

I assume `image` is the url to the image.

In markdown

```markdown
{% for post in site.posts %} 
{% assign author = site.authors[page.author] %} 

{: .avatar .avatar-sm }
![{{ post.author }}]({{ author.image | relative_url }})

{% endfor %}
```

In html

```html
{% for post in site.posts %} 
{% assign author = site.authors[page.author] %} 

<img src="{{ author.image | relative_url }}" alt="{{ post.author }}" class="avatar avatar-sm">

{% endfor %}
```